Using a Latching Button for Car Hazard Lights with LED Indicator
I'm attempting to learn more about electronics with this small project
I am using a latching button .
I connected the button to the ignition wire of the car because I want the LED to stay on.
My problem is that when I press the button, I also want the button's LED to start blinking, as this button activates the car's hazard lights. If I push the button again, the hazard lights will turn off, and the LED should return to its previous state.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

How can I modify the circuit to make the LED blink when the button is pressed and return to a steady state when the button is pressed again?
